# Regexp string match function not working after new Regex call

Tags: jquery, regex, string, replace, mat

I have create one equation solver program.In my final step i got some error.is shown below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.solve').click(function () {
   var str1 = $('#equ').val();
  var select = $('#selected').text();// x value
     var fnd = str1.split(new RegExp(select,"g")); // x value split
    var fnd_demo = $('#demo').html('without x='+fnd);// without x
  var final = fnd_demo.replace(/([\-+])?\s*(\d+)?([a-z])/g, '');//replace all alpha numeric into space
      $('#demo1').text('only numeric'+final);//display the numeric only(error:not show any result) applied with 'text('work')' this also not work
    
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter equation"  value="10x+10z-108k+10y-10x+50" class="equ" id="equ">
<input type="button" value="solve" class="solve" id="solve" onclick="solve()">
<p id="selected">x</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
```

`x` value get  from some selected id and applied to regex with new Regexp and getting some result.That result  was replace with space is not working at the time apply with some of the text to print that's also not working.`demo1 not working.`Whats is the reason and correct my code. my expect answer is only numeric values like this :`10,-10,+50`Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to evaluate a mathematical expression, you can use  [JavaScript Expression Evaluator library](http://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/)  or [mathjs](http://mathjs.org/) to simplify your work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you want something like this,

```
> var s = '10x+10z-108k+10y-10x+50'
> s.match(/[+-]?\d+(?=x|$)/g)
[ '10', '-10', '+50' ]
```

or

```
> var v = 'x';
> s.match(RegExp("[+-]?\\d+(?=" + v + "|$)", "g"))
[ '10', '-10', '+50' ]
```

Comment: or `s.match(RegExp("[+-]?\\d+(?=" + v + "|\\b)", "g"))`

Comment: ya thank u so much Avinash raj. But what's the reason` $('#demo1')` not printing any text ?.Even apply text `('something')` not getting a output.why?

Comment: Why don't you use match instead of split `var fnd = str1.match(RegExp("[+-]?\\d+(?=" + select + "|\\b)", "g"));`

Comment: ok Thanks.If i get the result without comma what should i do?

Comment: just join the result with comma as delim